# Excel: Grading Formula to Omit Certain Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet I've made for a class.

I have pre-filled in all of the assignments:

```
 |      A      |       B        |     C
 |-------------------------------------------
1|Assignments  |Points Received |Total Points
2|Assignment 1 |10              |10
3|Assignment 2 |?               |10
4|Quiz 1       |9               |10
5|Assignment 3 |?               |10  
6|...          |                |
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can sum up the points under total for only those cells that have an actual number in the cell directly left to it.  Or, get the sum of the total points if the left cell isn't "?".  How can I do this?  I do not want to remove the points in Total Points column for which the is an associated "?" symbol in the Points Received column.

Essentially, I want the grade to display the current percent of only completed assignments (in the example it would be 19/20, not 19/40)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the top left cell (Assignments) in your example is A1...

For Points Received, use the regular SUM() function. It will treat the non-numeric cells as zeros:

```
=SUM(B2:B5)
```

For Total Points, use the SUMIF() function:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B5,">0",C2:C5)
```

This tells Excel to look at the cells in B2:B5 (Points Received) and IF they meet the criteria (>0) then take the SUM of corresponding cells in C2:C5 (Total Points).

Comment: I did update my submission to include the column labels.  I will try your solution now.